# Interview Follow up

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, hiring-process

I got done with a final round interview yesterday and got good feelings about it. I sent a courtesy email to the talent acquisition manager. However, the email it sent to was not her own but a generic @jobvite.com email and I am not a 100% sure if she received it. I was thinking of emailing their hr email with the same courtesy email but would that be overbearing if she read it twice? They told me multiple times throughout the interview if I have any questions after the interview, feel free to email the hr email address they have. What are your thoughts?

Comment: can you contact the company and get her actual email? Or hand-deliver a thank you note if the company is local? Would probably be easier than trying to hit multiple email addresses, since you likely wouldn't get a response even if read (unless you are asking a question, and maybe not even then).

Comment: Not sure why you are claiming this to be a duplicate when I clearly stated I sent a courtesy email before hand but noticed it went to a generic email that is most likely not her own. Please read my question fully before declaring this being a duplicate.

Comment: @ryekayo -  I did read the question,  and rereading it I still feel it's either a duplicate or specific to your situation,  so off topic for this forum.

Comment: Its not a duplicate. The question you made a reference to is with a different scenario altogether. That question states the person already sent an email and is waiting days later with no response. My scenario is that I sent an email and not because of the uncertainty of the address I sent it to, would sending another email to their hr email would be too overbearing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I was thinking of emailing their hr email with the same courtesy email but would that be overbearing if she read it twice?

No, a second email would not be overbearing. In fact, it would communicate your interest in the job.

Now a **tenth** email might be overbearing, but a second is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5):

> I was thinking of emailing their hr email with the same courtesy email
>   but would that be overbearing if she read it twice? They told me
>   multiple times throughout the interview if I have any questions after
>   the interview, feel free to email the hr email address they have. What
>   are your thoughts?

Since you are concerned that your email may not have reached the intended audience, it makes perfect sense to send it to the HR email address they specifically gave you.

I wouldn't be bothered if I got two emails through different channels.

For future communications, use the email they specify.